# How can i run a function in azure using my own custom AuthorizationLevel?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have published a Function App in Azure with AuthorizationLevel of Function. So i access the endpoint the user needs to have a key. 
Can I change this so that I have my own key ?
The code i am using in the app is

```
        [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(**"myownazurekey"**, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {   .....
```

So can i set myownazurekey in azure to be retrieved instead of using the defined master / default keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You need to read [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatefunctionsecret) first.

You can use to send http requests in your C # code to obtain or modify the function key and host key (which can also include deletion, etc.). The use and storage of function key and host key are handled according to your business.

If u need `HttpHelper.cs`, you can see my code. https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleProj/blob/master/ODatafilter/HttpHelper.cs

[image]

*Test in Postman*

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

You don't need `**"myownazurekey"**,`  in your code.  You can follow my step to create your custom key to access your function app.

1. Create function app in portal.
2. Go to resource, find `Functions -> App Keys -> + New host key`, then input name `custonkey` and value `0510wxwc`.
3. Deploy your function apps.

   Sample function code:

   ```
   [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
   {
       log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

       string name = req.Query["test"];

       return new OkObjectResult(name);
   }
   ```
4. Copy Url from portal like pic

[image].

5. Test in postman.

[image]

Comment: That is fine , but if the key is renewed , it will give unauthorised error.

Comment: I dont want to always retrieve the key from the portal . Looking for a way to save the key in maybe the vault and call the function with that key (a static key value) ?

Comment: I will try to use powershell to add host key then you can save it. I think it will the best way for u.@Debbie.S

Comment: Or i could retrieve the current default host key and attach it to the url before invoking the function ? That should work ?

Comment: @Debbie.S Yes, of course it is possible. The main problem at present is that the host key cannot be modified directly on the portal after the release is completed. It is certainly the best to retrieve the available host key.

Comment: @Debbie.S If you need it, I can use powershell to try to create and save the host key. I personally feel that there is no need to use it like this, get all the host keys on the portal, manually save it in the database and encode to achieve this function, I think the coding implementation is still more troublesome.

Comment: @Debbie.S https://memoryleek.wordpress.com/2018/11/20/setting-an-azure-function-host-key-at-deploy-time-with-azure-devops/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214874/discussion-between-jason-and-debbie-s).